# Deletion of a polygonal selection

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to highlight selected polygons and then send it to another vector layer. I'm be able to do this with the code below:

```
  const ghostDataLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(....
  let drawingSource = new ol.source.Vector({useSpatialIndex: false});

  let draw;

  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'Polygon',
    source: drawingSource,
    style: style
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);


  function highlightSelection(drawnPolygon) {
      ghostDataLayer.getSource().forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(drawnPolygon, function(feature) {

          selectedFeatureCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

          const selectedGeometry = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(selectedFeatureCoordinates);
          const selectedPolygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: selectedGeometry
          });
          const selectedSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [selectedPolygonFeature]
          });
          const selectedLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: selectedSource,
            style: selectedPolygonStyle,
            zIndex: 99,
          });
          map.addLayer(selectedLayer);

      });
  };


  draw.on('drawstart', function(event){
    drawingSource.clear();
  }, this);

  draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
    let drawnPolygonExtent = event.feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
    highlightSelection(drawnPolygonExtent);
  });
```

Problems comes when I draw a new polygon. In that case the previous selection doesn't vanish and the new selection is added to the previous.

[image]

In the image above polygons 23840, 23869, 23744 are a part of a selection; 23744, 23897 and 23750 are a part to another selection. Polygon with id 23744 is shared between the two selection.

How I can clean the previous selection when star a draw of a new polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a new layer to the map for each selected feature.  If you have a single source and layer you can clear it before adding more features

```
  const selectedSource = new ol.source.Vector();
  const selectedLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: selectedSource,
    style: selectedPolygonStyle,
    zIndex: 99,
  });
  map.addLayer(selectedLayer);

  function highlightSelection(drawnPolygon) {
      selectedSource.clear();
      ghostDataLayer.getSource().forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(drawnPolygon, function(feature) {

          selectedFeatureCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

          const selectedGeometry = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(selectedFeatureCoordinates);
          const selectedPolygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: selectedGeometry
          });
          selectedSource.addFeature(selectedPolygonFeature);

      });

  };
```